# Large filesize of PDF output from spplot

Tags: r, pdf, lattice

Using a truncated shapefile and some data that I have added, I have created a colored map using spplot. However, when I export the created graph as a PDF, the filesize is very large and so is the final document. (The PDF is around 50 MB).

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?  I am not sure if I can provide a minimum working example, since the shapefile is also quite large (300MB).

Alternatively, is there any way to reduce the file-size after the fact?

Comment: Does it have to be PDF?  For example, is an SVG or postscript version smaller?

Comment: PostScript files give me trouble with PDFLatex,  but that is an option. I managed to "solve" the problem by changing to a much smaller and lower resolution shape-file. Since the image quality has not suffered, I think the initial file was much too detailed.

Answer (score 2):

To cite Prof Brian Ripley in http://markmail.org/message/ravkpnjexagmpm4o

*If* compression is enough, pdf() in R-devel does it, as does cairo_pdf() in current R. And there are other ways than Acrobat to compress/compact a PDF file: see ?tools::compactPDF and the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

Comment: The `compress` argument for `pdf` is available in R-2.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to pdf I suggest to generate a high resolution png. I have submitted such pngs without any problem to journals such as computers and geosciences. Using such a png makes the documents they are put into much more workable. If you want to stick to pdf, pdftk (pdf toolkit) allows you to compress pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tools)    
help(compactPDF)
```